# WPF X:Name causes type name 'ViewModel' Compile Error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, namespaces, behavior, visualstates

I intend to set a state of CalibrationGridControl from a button.
To do that, the CalibrationGridControl UserControl must have a x:Name (Blend even adds one for me when I setup the the GoToState behavior.
Problem is, as soon as I add x:Name="calibrationGridControl" I get the following compile error.

Error   CS0426  The type name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the type 'TeachpendantControl'  TeachPendantControl C:\GitRepos\SolutionName\TheWPFControl\Views\HandeyeCalibration\HandeyeCalibrationView.xaml 150 38  Build   Active  Compiler

The UserControl HandeyeCalibrationView below is a View to be shown inside a ContentControl in the  "TheWPFControl". TheWPFControl and the HandyeCalibration.xaml are both in the same project (a WPF Control library). Below is the essential part of the HandeyeCalibration.xaml file where I get the error.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl.ViewModel"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Wpf.Behaviours"
xmlns:HandeyeCalibration="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl.ViewModel.H"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
x:Class="TeachpendantControl.Views.HandeyeCalibrationView" 
mc:Ignorable="d"  
d:DataContext ="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:HandeyeCalibrationViewModel}, 
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
Height="111.221" 
Width="276.813"
>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Mode="OneWay" 
             Path="HandeyeCalibrationViewModel" 
             Source="{StaticResource Locator2}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
 <Grid> 
 <UserControl>
...

          <HandeyeCalibration:CalibrationGridControl 
            x:Name="calibrationGridControl"                                             
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="106" 
            Width="106"                
            Background="#FF747474"/>    
     <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" 
           Content="{Binding AddText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           Margin="0,0,5,0">
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                   <ei:GoToStateAction TargetName="calibrationGridControl" 
                      StateName="{Binding NextPositionState, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                   </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>                   
     </Button>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I only remove the x:Name="calibrationGridControl" line everything compiles just fine. What could be wrong, causing this strange error message?

I got some questions about the CalibrationGridControl. If I just remove the x:Name when adding it to another user control everything compiles. The XAML for the CalibrationGridControl looks like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TeachpendantControl.ViewModel.H.CalibrationGridControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl.ViewModel"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"             
             xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalibrationGridCrossBrush" Color="#FFFFDF00"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalibrationGridPositionTrainedFillBrush" Color="#FFFFDF00"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalibrationGridPositionFillBrush" Color="Black"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>        
        ...            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Sounds like the issue is possibly with this line
    xmlns:HandeyeCalibration="clr-namespace:TeachpendantControl.ViewModel.H"

Is that namespace correct? Your control is within a "ViewModel" namespace?

Comment: Looks strange indeed, but it seems correct. The user control was created in the ViewModel namespace (Visual Studio added it there by default). The .H I just tried since before it was HandeyeCalibration and I wanted to make there was no risk of class and namespace collision so therefore I just set it  to H

Comment: In the meantime I recreated the CalibrationGridControl as a new UserControl. I placed it under my Views folder, then Visual Studio set the namespace to TeachpendantControl.Views. Now I get the same compile error but it complains about type Views instead of ViewModel.

Comment: Could you add the x:Class line from the CalibrationGridControl view?

Comment: The issue may be with that CalibrationGridControl, if it is unable to compile the control (and that control will be the only item in the namespace) it will not be able to find the namespace.

Comment: @MartinGrundy I have added the code for the CalibrationGridControl.xaml. In the code behind I have removed all code so it looks as a default new user control, but the problem is still present.

Comment: Is TeachpendantControl a control *and* a namespace?

Comment: @mm8 Yes that is correct.

Comment: @mm8 Ha! I assumed based on your question that it could make sense to change the name of the TeachpendantControl class name to something different than the namespace name. It made the trick and as a bonus now blend animations seems to work as well.
Please feel free to post that it makes sense to change the name of the control to avoid class and namespace collision and I will set it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TeachpendantControl` apparently is both a type *and* a namespace.

You should either change the name of the control or the change the name of the namespace to avoid a naming collision.

Comment: This prompted me to look for the same problem in my failing code and it helped. Unlike many other suggestions to restart VS or switch build configuration, etc. I wish the error message was more clear as what the cause might be.